# How to cancel the starting run and let the pending run finish in Github Actions?

Tags: concurrency, github-actions, cicd

At the Github Actions docs, they explain how to use concurrency to cancel an ongoing run when starting a new run. I want the opposite case: I want to cancel any starting runs and wait for the pending run to finish

Has anyone dealt with a situation like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idconcurrency), if you set `cancel-in-progress: false` in-progress jobs will finish. Now if you want to cancel and queued jobs, then you'll need to ad a final step to your job and manually call the API to cancel queued jobs.
That way GHA will keep it pending until you manually cancel them.

In a typical use-case I'd advise against doing pending job cancellation, but there are always exceptions, but thread lightly with something like this :)